# Using a Bluetooth receiver with 3.5mm jack headset

Tags: bluetooth, transceiver, headphones

For the past 1/2 year I have been using a cordless Bluetooth headset ([this one](https://www.iluv.com/collections/true-wireless/products/neonair)) connected with my motorcycle Garmin GPS device. While connected the device will not allow me to control the volume over it's own interface but only through it's own buttons (+/- buttons).

The thing is that while wearing all my motorcycle equipment such as leather jacket / gloves it is almost impossible to locate the button I want because it's resting somewhere under my jacket and has very small buttons. Also the size and shape of these earplugs is not quite big for my new tighter helmet and after a couple of hours it causes pain. Finally the headset's battery is quite small providing sound for 2-2.5 hours max.

Before that I have been using a plain 3.5 mm normal headset with stereo headphones, mic and button ([this one](https://www.snapdeal.com/product/samsung-eoig935bw-in-ear-wired/639838223687)) wearing them for 4+ hours without any pain issues.

Is there a way to connect this plain pair on a separate Bluetooth transceiver (listening only is ok but talking as well is preferred) with a small size factor that would be attached on a convenient place on my helmet so that I can control volume via it's buttons (preferably big ones) and at the same time being able to wear them for longer period?

How can I search for such a device?

Comment: did you do a google search on "bluetooth audio receiver"?

Comment: @ratchet freak Only to find house application devices (requiring separate power supply) and smaller devices that only RECEIVE sound and have no control buttons...

Comment: This seems like a *usage* question (or even a part shopping one) not a *design* question and so does not really fit here.  In terms of if you can use input controls from one bluetooth device to control behavior of another, that would really depend on the software on the phone, which is not on topic here either.

Comment: This is a pure consumer electronic gadget question.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using Sony [SBH20](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00C1CGZT0) for this purpose. You can try [this one](https://www.bestbuy.com/site/aluratek-bluetooth-audio-receiver-and-transmitter/5715709.p?skuId=5715709&intl=nosplash) also (attach a small power bank for powering the device).

- The first one is small in size but it might be difficult to interface with the adjustment controls. Whereas the second one is a little big but the adjustment controls are better.
- Apart from the above factors both can be connected to your existing headphones and have quit a similar feature set.
- Unfortunately, the answer to your question is too broad & with just a google search you will have the ability to choose from a lot of product options then the ones mentioned here.
- You need to do a search for *Bluetooth receiver*. Most of the results would be something like a USB dongle but a few results should match your needs.